# Combinatorics - Colouring

Tags: combinatorics

I have a colouring of the edges of $K_{11}$. I need to prove that there is a vertex $v$ such that at least $6$ of the edges incident to $v$ are the same colour. I think a proof by contradiction is the right way to go about this question and I think the solution can be reached using the Pigeonhole principle and Ramsey's Theory.

Comment: You should put some effort when asking a question. This site is not for copypasting your homework.

Answer (score 3):

If not, every vertex is incident to five edges of each color. That’s a total of exactly $\dfrac{5\cdot11}2$ blue edges. A bit awkward, that!

Comment: Please could you expand on this?

Comment: @user61547:  each edge has two ends.  If each vertex has five blue edges coming in, you have an odd number of ends, so half an edge.

Comment: @user61547: Or to put it another way, throw away the red edges. You now have a graph with $11$ vertices and the blue edges. Each vertex has degree $5$, so the sum of the degrees of the vertices is $55$. But the sum of the degrees of the vertices is always twice the number of edges, so your graph has $55/2$ edges. This is impossible.